# Обновление GridView и HashMap

Tags: android, android-sdk, gridview

Помогите чет туплю.
У меня GridView содержит список категорий, тыкая по одной из них мне нужно отображать галочку(Что типа выбрал) и убирать все галочки у выбранных ранее(Т.е в один момент времени может быть выделена тока одна категория).Галочки я реализовал с помощью скрытых LinearLayout c иконкой галочки. Множественный выбор у меня работает т.е я могу выделять все категории, а при повторном нажатии убирать выделение. Но я не понимаю как мне в один момент времени делать активной тока выбранную категорию, а другие скрывать.

Категории я решил делать через HashMap, что бы хранить тама не только названия категорий, но и состояния(нажал/не нажал).

Вот HashMap:

```
public class  HashMapCategory{
   public static Map<Integer, ObjCategory> hashmap = null;  

     public static  Map<Integer, ObjCategory> getHash(){
        Map<Integer, ObjCategory> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, ObjCategory>();
         hashmap.put(0, new ObjCategory(0,"Категория0",R.id.llLabelApply,false));
         hashmap.put(1, new ObjCategory(1,"Категория1",R.id.llLabelApply,false));
         hashmap.put(2, new ObjCategory(2,"Категория2",R.id.llLabelApply,false));
         hashmap.put(3, new ObjCategory(3,"Категория3",R.id.llLabelApply,false));
         hashmap.put(4, new ObjCategory(4,"Категория4",R.id.llLabelApply,false));
         hashmap.put(5, new ObjCategory(5,"Категория5",R.id.llLabelApply,false));

        return hashmap;

         }


}
```

Вот инициализация GridView в методе onCreateView:

```
//Переменные
Map<Integer, ObjCategory> hashMapCategory;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
GridView gridView;


//Обьект содержащий названия категорий и статусы
 hashMapCategory = HashMapCategory.getHash();
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_items_upr_for,R.id.tvText, HashMapToString.toStringArray(hashMapCategory));
          gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
          gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Метод onItemClick:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {



        View ll = parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.llLabelApply);


             //Этот код работает он позволяет выделять все элементы, а при повторном нажатии скрывать иконку выделения
          Set<Map.Entry<Integer, ObjCategory>> set = hashMapCategory.entrySet();
        // Отобразим набор
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ObjCategory> me : set) {


            if(position == hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getNumber()){   
                if(hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getStatus()){
                    ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).setStatus(false);

                }else{
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).setStatus(true);

                }
            }


        }      

    }
```

Comment: А вам нужно делать наоборот) с начало все скрыть а потом отобразить галочку на той на которую нажали.

Answer (score 1):

Все родил):

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, ObjCategory>> set = hashMapCategory.entrySet();
        // Отобразим набор
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ObjCategory> me : set) {

            View ll = parent.getChildAt(hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getNumber()).findViewById(hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getLlLabelApply());
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).setStatus(false);
            if(position == hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getNumber()){   

                if(hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getStatus()){
                    ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).setStatus(false);

                }else{
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).setStatus(true);

                }

            }

            Log.d("MyLogs",""+hashMapCategory.get(me.getKey()).getStatus());
        }
```